# How to retrieve specific UIImageView that the user clicked (or touched) on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have multiple UIImageViews on my single view. I need to click on one (say ImageView1) and then click on an empty space on the View. On this second click, the image assigned to ImageView1 should appear on this position, and disappear from on the position of the first click.

Example: While playing chess, a user clicks on the Queen, and clicks on an (permissible  move) empty slot. The Queen should have moved to the new spot. Similar way.

Should I use  TapGestures, UIControl or UIButton?

I was trying to use TapGestures's touchesBegan - but this worked only if I had just one UIImageView. [I don't care about automating the move, so I ignored touchesMoved].

When there are multiple ImageViews, and when an user clicks on an ImageView, how do I know which Image the user clicked on?

Comment: what you have tried yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two questions here:

#### 1 - What to use when implementing interaction with UIViews?

Well, answer depends on what you wish to achieve.

If you'd like a simple button functionality (i.e. single tap) use `UIButton`.

If you'd like to customuze your control's functionality, subclass `UIControl` and implement the functionality you need.

If you're looking for low level hacks subclass `UIView` and override the relevant methods.

#### 2 - How to detect which view was tapped?

There are many ways to do that.
One way them which will work in all of the above mentioned ways would be to assign an identifying integer into the `UIView` `tag` property and then when the view is tapped query the `tag` property and compare it to your view.

Example:

```
// Somewhere in your initialization code
// ...
[_myTappableView setTag:123];
```

When the tap is recognized:

```
if (tappedView.tag == 123)
{
    NSLog("My Tappable View was tapped!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a gesture recogniser to your image view..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have tried before, but there is a method 'didselectitematindexpath' and you can use tap gesture as well.